# Return Changed value of Parameter in OCAML

Tags: ocaml, utop

```
let rule1 m = 
    m = m/2;
    m
```

**rule1(250)** should return **125** but instead returns **250**.

How is it possible to return an updated value of a parameter?

Comment: As I stated in the other comment, `= : 'a -> 'a -> bool` is the comparison operator. If you want to assign a local variable you need to use `let m = m / 2 in ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `m` is mutable? The `m = ..` statement will not update the provided argument. Would returning the updated value be an option?

```
let rule1 m = 
    m/2
```

Comment: yes that works!, I have another question, How is it possible to create a variable and assign it the value returned by a function? Example: let rule1 m = m/2; let var = rule1 var.

Comment: `m = m/2` will not create a local version, it will produce a boolean because `= : 'a -> 'a -> bool` is the comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you genuinely wish to mutate the value of a binding, that binding has to be a `ref` or a record type with a mutable field (which a `ref` is one specific example of with handy syntactic sugar.)

```
let m = ref 12 in
  (m := !m / 2;
   print_int !m;
   print_newline ())
```

However, using mutable state like this likely means you're writing non-idiomatic OCaml code, and there is something you're missing: either a more elegant solution, or in the case of learning, the point of an algorithm lesson.

Or usually both, of course. I speak from personal experience.